# GNU grep -P option mismatch with Perl regular expression

Tags: regex, perl, grep

See very simple output of `grep -P`, on a 1 line file:

```
[ldagan:dfII]cat test
oh,this,is,config,2
[ldagan:dfII]grep -icP '\S+?,config,' test
0
```

However, getting the string to match within Perl regular expression does match!
See below:

```
[ldagan:dfII]perl -e ' if ("oh,this,is,config,2" =~/\S+?,config,/ )  
{print "yey!\n"} else {print "ney!\n"} ;'
yey!
```

I am using GNU grep version 2.5.1

Comment: make this: `=~/\S+?,config,` to this:  `=~/[^[:space:]]+?,config,` add the `-P` flag also

Comment: Hello Avinash. The -c was intended to show that there are no matches. W/o it, one gets 0 lines.

Comment: `grep -ic ',config,'` is equivalent and simpler. Is there a complication you're not telling us?

Comment: Yes, it is an excerpt from a larger file, that I cannot share, and I need it after the third comma.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider updating grep. It works fine with GNU grep version 2.16:

```
$ /bin/grep -icP '\S+?,config,' test
1
```

Remember that the `-P` feature in grep is still experimental.

Answer (score 0):

There 2 solutions, one is to update the grep, just as Arkanosis suggested.
The second is similar to what vihan1086 suggested.
Use

```
grep -iCP '[^ ]+?' test
```